# Using target on div without a href

Tags: html, css

I have created a row div with id"dashboard" in which i have 3 divs. And below this row i have created 3 rows with one div in each row. I want to click on one div in row div with id"dashboard" and open the row div with id "alarm". I want to use target to acheive this task but unfortunately target can only be used with a href tag. Here is my code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>My Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>



<div id="dashboard" class="row" >

    <div  class="col-4" style="background-color:#009">
    </div>

    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#C00">
    </div>

    <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#0C0">
    </div>

</div> 



<div id="alarm" class="row" >

    <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#009">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="calendar" class="row" >

    <div class="col-12" style="background-color:C00">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="weather" class="row" >

    <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#0C0">
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is its css code:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;

}

.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

.show{
    display: none;


    }

.show:target{
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Target isn't the correct way to do it anyway.  Put an "onclick=" on the div, and write a Javascript function to handle its behavior.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I know i can use onclick . But i just wanted to ask if i can still do it somehow using target

Comment: You can achieve it if you use `<a>` tags instead of these `<div>`'s

Comment: @Mi-Creativity I'm gonna try it rn and share with u the outcome

Comment: @SherazShahidButt, I've posted it as an answer, check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/LgehLvnq/1/), this is a CSS only solution, just replace your `div`'s with `a`'s and making use of the `:target` it will work the way you want:

```css
   @charset"utf-8";

   /* CSS Document */
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .row:after {
     content: "";
     clear: both;
     display: block;
   }
   [class*="col-"] {
     float: left;
     padding: 15px;
   }
   .col-1 {
     width: 8.33%;
   }
   .col-2 {
     width: 16.66%;
   }
   .col-3 {
     width: 25%;
   }
   .col-4 {
     width: 33.33%;
   }
   .col-5 {
     width: 41.66%;
   }
   .col-6 {
     width: 50%;
   }
   .col-7 {
     width: 58.33%;
   }
   .col-8 {
     width: 66.66%;
   }
   .col-9 {
     width: 75%;
   }
   .col-10 {
     width: 83.33%;
   }
   .col-11 {
     width: 91.66%;
   }
   .col-12 {
     width: 100%;
   }
   .show {
     display: none;
   }
   :target {
     display: block;
   }
```

```html
<div id="dashboard" class="row">
  <a href="#alarm" class="col-4" style="background-color:#009"></a>
  <a href="#calendar" class="col-4" style="background-color:#C00"></a>
  <a href="#weather" class="col-4" style="background-color:#0C0"></a>
</div>
<div id="alarm" class="row show">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#009"></div>
</div>
<div id="calendar" class="row show">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#C00"></div>
</div>
<div id="weather" class="row show">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#0C0"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Update:** Upon a request in the comment, now with adding an `<a href="#dashboard">` in each one of the `.show` gadgets and performing the same `:target` trick we have this result [**JS Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/m9fn9qpr/):

```css
   @charset"utf-8";

   /* CSS Document */
   * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   .row:after {
     content: "";
     clear: both;
     display: block;
   }
   [class*="col-"] {
     float: left;
     padding: 15px;
   }
   .col-1 {
     width: 8.33%;
   }
   .col-2 {
     width: 16.66%;
   }
   .col-3 {
     width: 25%;
   }
   .col-4 {
     width: 33.33%;
   }
   .col-5 {
     width: 41.66%;
   }
   .col-6 {
     width: 50%;
   }
   .col-7 {
     width: 58.33%;
   }
   .col-8 {
     width: 66.66%;
   }
   .col-9 {
     width: 75%;
   }
   .col-10 {
     width: 83.33%;
   }
   .col-11 {
     width: 91.66%;
   }
   .col-12 {
     width: 100%;
   }
   .show {
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 400px;
     top: 0;
   }
   :target {
     display: block;
   }
   .back-btn {
     width: 60px;
     height: 40px;
     display: inline-block;
     z-index: 20;
     background-color: orange;
     position: absolute;
     padding-top: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: black;
   }
```

```html
<div id="dashboard" class="row">
  <a href="#alarm" class="col-4" style="background-color:#009"></a>
  <a href="#calendar" class="col-4" style="background-color:#C00"></a>
  <a href="#weather" class="col-4" style="background-color:#0C0"></a>

</div>
<div id="alarm" class="alarm row show">
  <a href="#dashboard" class="back-btn">back</a>
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#009; height:300px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="calendar" class="row show">
  <a href="#dashboard" class="back-btn">back</a>
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#C00; height:300px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="weather" class="row show">
  <a href="#dashboard" class="back-btn">back</a>
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#0C0; height:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

** *NOTE that I've added `height:300px;` to the inline style of the `.show` DIVs*.

Comment: This is actually very nice. Hadn't use :target before.

Comment: It is indeed, check this for another practical pure css example https://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity This works perfectly. But i want to hide the top row after i have clicked a particular a href . How can i acheive that?

Comment: you mean the 3 `<a>`'s row? how'd you click other options if you hide it?

Comment: @Mi-Creativity i will add a back button which will point back to that row. Basically i'm making a dashboard which contains a calender , an alarm and weather gadget. Once i click any of the item mentioned above they would open up and the dashboard will hide. I can go back using the back button.

Comment: @SherazShahidButt, check it now I've updated the answer

Comment: @Mi-Creativity This is perfect. Can you tell me how did you hide the dashboard row when any particular div is clicked. I think this has something to do with postion:absolute.

Comment: The combination of `position:absolute` to make it positioned freely, with the `top:0;` to move it up make the gadgets `div`'s cover the `#dashboard` when their `display:block`...

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Thanks a lot. Wish i could vote up but unfortunately my rep is 1 . Keep up the good work

Comment: No worries man, I'm glad it helped, you can check this as an answer so that people know it is the correct answer for your OP, best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Target isn't the correct way to do it anyway. Put an "onclick=" on the div, and write a Javascript function to handle the behavior.

```
    <div id="dashboard" class="row">

        <div  class="col-4" style="background-color:#009" onclick="myfunction('col4')">
        </div>
</div>

       function myfunction(whichColumn){
          //do some stuff with whichColumn
       }
```