# Looking to use CSS "display" and ":target" to create a tabbing nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to create a "tabber" style navbar while using no scripting whatsoever.  However I'm having issues figuring out how to make a default image appear when none of the other spans are the target.  I am VERY new to CSS, so in addition to this question any recommendations are appreciated.

More in-depth description, usage, and restrictions can be found below the code.

### CSS

```css
/* Hide stage# images on page load */
.infobox .stages .stage1, .stage2, .stage3, .stage4 {
    display:none;
}

/* Display Image when anchor link is clicked */
.infobox #thisstage1:target {
    display:inline
}

.infobox #thisstage2:target {
    display:inline
}

.infobox #thisstage3:target {
    display:inline
}

.infobox #thisstage4:target {
    display:inline
}
```

### HTML

```html
<table class="infobox">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="stages">
            <!-- Tabber Style Navbar Containing Links -->
            <td>
                <a href="#thisstage1">Stage 1</a>
                "-"
                <a href="#thisstage2">Stage 2</a>
                "-"
                <a href="#thisstage3">Stage 3</a>
                "-"
                <a href="#thisstage4">Stage 4</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <!-- Images to show when corresponding span is targeted via above Links -->
            <td>
                <span class="stage1" id="thisstage1">
                    <a href="...stage1.png">
                        <img src="...stage1.png">
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="stage2" id="thisstage2">
                    <a href="...stage2.png">
                        <img src="...stage2.png">
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="stage3" id="thisstage3">
                    <a href="...stage3.png">
                        <img src="...stage3.png">
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span class="stage4" id="thisstage4">
                    <a href="...stage4.png">
                        <img src="...stage4.png">
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Detailed Description:

I have 4 links (Stage1, Stage2, Stage3, and Stage4).  I also have 4 images.  When I click on the links, I want the targeted image to be shown and all other images to disappear.  The CSS is straightforward in accomplishing this much.

However, when the page is loaded and none of the links are the target, no image is displayed.  I would like for Stage1.png to be shown if no other links are the target.

I tried this & a LOT of similar things with different selectors:

```
.thisstages .stage1 span:nth-last-of-type(4) [display=none] {
    display:inline
}

.servantstages span:nth-last-of-type(4) [display=none] .stage1  {
    display:inline
}
```

However, usually, Stage1 was shown directly before The targeted Stage.  I'd also like to stay away from specifying attributes, like above, as I've read that it can slow things down.  However, I'm new to this, so I don't have many options here.  Any and all input is greatly appreciated.

### Usage & Restrictions

I'm going to be implementing this on a Wikia specifically to reduce vertical scroll on mobile devices.  On top of that, I am limited in what I can do as far as HTML is concerned.  The HTML tags usable on Wikia are somewhat restricted, however I don't see this causing an issue.  I'm avoiding scripting for 2 reasons.  The first being that Wikia requires an approval window, and I have a bad habit of tweaking things.  The second is mobile devices.

## Other Notes

So it appears that using the method below by Mi-Creativity doesn't function correctly on some phones (Probably due to Wikia's JavaScript).  So I played around some more with CSS trying to concentrate on using only display:.  After a lot more searching I ran across several different methods of using combinators to achieve what I'm looking for.  Here's the results (No guarantee on mobile compatibility, currently untested but hopeful):

### CSS

```css
.stages > .stage:target ~ .stage:last-child, .stages> stage {
    display:none
}

.stages > :last-child, .stages > .stage:target  {
    display:block
}
```

### HTML

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="link2">Link Text</a>
    <a href="link3">Link Text</a>
    ...More Links here if needed...
</div>

<div class="stages">
    <div id="link2" class="stage">
        ...Content...
    </div>
    <div id="link3" class="stage">
        ...Content...
    </div>
    ...More divs here if needed...
    <div id="home" class="stage">
        This is the default content, must be the last div nested in "stages"
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from an [answer to a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766865/using-target-on-div-without-a-href/33767234#33767234) , [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/m9fn9qpr/)

---

As from a comment, to show the first panel when page load, set a `display` for only this one - *depending on its `id` or add a unique `class`* - , also giving the `.show` class an `absolute` positioning and `top` value to shift it down  [**JS Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/59jL88f9/)

**CSS:**

```
.show {
  display: none; 
  position:absolute;
  top:38px;
  width:calc(100vw - 10px);
  height:300px;
}
#alarm {
  top:38px;
  display:block;
}
.2nd{
  z-index: 10;
}
:target {
  display:block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dashboard" class="row">
  <a href="#alarm" class="col-4" style="background-color:#009"></a>
  <a href="#calendar" class="col-4" style="background-color:#C00"></a>
  <a href="#weather" class="col-4" style="background-color:#0C0"></a>
</div>
<div id="alarm" class="row show">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#009;height:300px"></div>
</div>
<div id="calendar" class="row show 2nd">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#C00;height:300px"></div>
</div>
<div id="weather" class="row show 2nd">
  <div class="col-12" style="background-color:#0C0;height:300px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had previously considered z-index as a possibility, but had forgotten about it (probably because I've never used it).  I may rework it & see what I can do.  Appreciate the input.

Comment: The use of `z-index` was because the OP wanted the navbar to hide as he mentioned in a comment, you don't need to use `z-index` if you won't show your panel above the nav - *as hiding the nav behind it*

Comment: I read that answer way way too fast, my bad.  I see what's happening now.  My issue is, I need for that blue background that appears when the first tab is clicked to show up when the page loads & when it's targeted.  I also need it to go away when another tab is clicked.  That's where I keep running into my issue.

Comment: @CharlesVanceTerry, check my edited answer, it is working for this demonstration but you need to test it well for real site, something else to consider if you are going to implement this, you have to make sure that the `height` value of the *BLUE* panel is *NOT* more than the other two panels height

Comment: Ok I see how that works now & that will work perfectly.  I greatly appreciate the help.